# Get the exact SessionID generated in another Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am new to sql. In my Chat application, I am storing the messages with the help of following Database Tables.

---

```
SessionTable  -->  SessionID (PK)    Username1   Username2   Time
```

---

```
MessagesTable -->  SessionID (FK)    Username    Message     StartTime
```

---

The First Database Table `SessionTable` is used to generate a `SessionID` (IDENTITY(1,1)) by the help of which the users(limited to two) can have conversation. Whenever a user sends message to the other user, the message data will be stored in `MessagesTable` of column `Message` with the respective user's name in the column `Username` and the `Time` when the user sends the message. But the problem here I am facing is that how to get the exact sessionID to be stored along with the message in `MessagesTable` which was generated in `SessionTable` ?

My another question is that, As I am storing the messages in a single database Table will it arise performance issues in future? (The project which I am creating will be used among atmost 30 members) and also please suggest whether the way I have designed the Database tables is better way of approach or not.

Comment: As far as table design goes, it would be very limiting if you decided to extend your chat application in future where conversation can have multiple parties and if user can broadcast/target message to specific user(s) within a conversation. But you can always re-factor the db design at later stage.

Comment: Good point from VinayC, you have to define the scope of implementation before designing the tables and tuning your queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you `insert` the row into `SessionTable` you can use the [`Scope_Identity()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx?ppud=4) function to get the `SessionID` assigned to the new row.

As for performance, there are too many factors to provide a useful answer.

Comment: I am not sure whether I can use Scope_Identity() here, as there is possibility that more than one conversation can start at a same time..Thus, the IDENTITY stored will be different.

Comment: @Mr_Green - The value returned is limited to the same scope as the `insert`.  If you have, for example, a stored procedure that adds the session row and returns the new session id then you can have several instances executing at the same time and each will return the correct result.

Comment: HABO and @ElYusubov, The way I have designed the Database tables is it ok? or do you have any suggestions to modify it?

Comment: @Mr_Green - The tables aren't bad.  I would include an identity column in the `MessagesTable` table (Hint: Sounding redundant yet?) just to ensure that every row has a unique identifier.  In a larger pond you would probably want a `Users` table.  It would let you separate out the user's name, store authentication information like a hashed password, contact information like an email address, ... .

Comment: Sorry, I cant understand why need of Identity column to `MessagesTable` ? Isn't it unnecessary to have.. please explain.

Comment: @Mr_Green - A identity column makes it easy to distinguish otherwise duplicate rows, e.g. if a "double tap" caused the same message to be sent twice within the resolution of your chosen `StartTime` data type.  It is also often useful when writing self joins to correlate rows within a table, as it lets you avoid pairing rows with themselves.  These arguments may not be applicable to your application at the moment, but the overhead is low enough that I would just add the column.  There is no requirement that it be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** It seems like you have one-to-many relationship between Session table and Message table. Thus, you are attempting to join the tables throw common `SessionID` column.

Depending on the messaging application load, you need to think about the indexing strategy as well. In another words, tables with high intensity of read & write are usually  getting performance hit.

**Solutiob #1:** You'll definitely need to use [**SCOPE_IDENTITY()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx).

```
DECLARE @SessionID INT;

INSERT INTO dbo.SessionTable  (Username1,   Username2,   Time)
SELECT 'User1', 'User2', GETDATE();

SELECT @SessionID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

After this creation of session, you would need to use `@SessionID` to add message detail in MessagesTable. Like the following code sample:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MessagesTable (SessionID, Username,  Message, StartTime)
SELECT @SessionID, 'User1', 'The sample text of the message' GETDATE();
GO
```

**In conclusion:** the overall principle is described in the code sample which is posted above. However, i did not check al the syntax, thus you may expect some syntax corrections in this code :)

Comment: Sorry, I cant understand your explanation..maybe because I am new to sql. (Do you mean to add a new column to MessagesTable as Primary key?)

Comment: no problem, just Google the how to add a primary key to the table :)

Comment: I added primary key and foreign key as I mentioned in my post as `pk` and `fk`. Will that add the rows automatically in my `MessagesTable` whenever `SessionID` generated in `SessionTable` ?

Comment: No, nothing happens automatically, you have to use the newly generated SessionID in SessionTable  in order to insert messages in MessagesTable .

Comment: How to call that newly generated SessionID in SessionTable to MessagesTable? So that I can store messages related to it..

Comment: @ElYusubov - re: "You'll definitely need to use SCOPE_IDENTITY()."  Actually, I prefer to use an `OUTPUT` clause on the `INSERT`.  It provides a set-based solution that is applicable to `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` and doesn't seem to suffer from the [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811/scope-identity-sometimes-returns-incorrect-value) that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` has had.  For a starter application I'm not too concerned, but `OUTPUT` is definitely a tool to have in one's pocket for more challenging problems.  And never `@@IDENTITY`.